# Auto Select Item from a List in SAPUI5/OpenUI5

Tags: sapui5

I have a search query for a list of products in `SAPUI5/OpenUI5`.

Is there a way that when my search query results into a single item, the app will automatically fire an event that will select that item?

Answer (score 0):

https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.List.html
Search for "fire" -> then you'll find methods like fireUpdateStartet (which replaces fireSelect) -->https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#fireUpdateStarted

Comment: I don't think that OP wants to fire the event him/herself. It might be better to attach a handler with `attachUpdateFinished`. The handler receives an object that contains the reason, the displayed # of items and the total # of items.

Comment: I will look into attachUpdateFinished. In the meanwhile, I have posted another question. Maybe you can help me on this also [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34720175/fire-barcodescannerbutton-after-view-loads

Comment: I tried bout attachUpdateFinished and fireUpdateStarted but it did not work. I was able to get the count of my result query. I was thinking that if my result is equal to one. The app will automatically click the item on the list. Unfortunately, still not luck on how to do this. I think I need to get the "event" when a user clicks an item and pass it to a method that actually displays the data on another view.

Answer (score 0):

using updateFinished you can achieve this as:

```js
oTable.attachUpdateFinished(function(oEvent) {

  //get the length of the Table
  if (oEvent.getSource().getItems().length == 1)

    //fire Selection on the ColumnListItem if there was only one Item
    oEvent.getSource().getItems()[0].firePress();


});
```

[Here's a working plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/SNpI5whzq3GyWfv08gLw/)

Let me know if this helps.